# Excel VBA - Send Email via CDO.message - cannot add attachment

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am following this tutorial to send emails via Gmail SMTP which is working well, but fails when it comes to adding an attachment.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/12/how-to-send-an-email-using-excel-macro-from-gmail-or-yahoo/

I am trying to send a copy of the active workbook which is saved into the users TEMP Appdata folder. I traced the temp file, checked for the files existence which is alright and should not be a problem, however, excel doesnt seem to attach it. I can however attach a file if I hardcode it (eg. "C:\temp\file.xls"), but not when the file path is given via variables.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I am out of ideas...

EDIT:
just to clarify, I tried several syntax's such as defining the path in the Gmail_Attachment variable or adding the TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr variables. None of them work, only if I literally code it as .addattachment "C:/path/file.xls" does it attach.

```
Sub Mail_Gmail()
'Working in 2000-2010
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb, Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath, TempFileName As String
    Dim SendTo, SendCC, Holidex, Property, QCI_Mgr, Position As Range
    Dim Gmail_ID, Gmail_PWD, Gmail_SMTP, Gmail_attachment As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set SendTo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B20")
    Set SendCC = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B21")
    Set Holidex = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B5")
    Set Property = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B4")
    Set QCI_Mgr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B14")
    Set Position = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B15")

    Gmail_SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Gmail_ID = "user@gmail.com"
    Gmail_PWD = "password"

    'Copy the sheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
        With ActiveSheet
            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
                ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
            End If

            '.ShowAllData                    ' disable autofilters
            .Cells.Copy
            .Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveSheet.Copy

    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 2000-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2010, we exit the sub when your answer is
            'NO in the security dialog that you only see  when you copy
            'an sheet from a xlsm file with macro's disabled.
            If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                With Application
                    .ScreenUpdating = True
                    .EnableEvents = True
                End With
                MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                Case 52:
                    If .HasVBProject Then
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                        'FileExtStr = ".pdf": FileFormatNum = 17
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    End If
                Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    End With


    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
    'With Destwb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:I50")
    '    .Select
    '    .Copy
    '    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'End With
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " _
                 & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")


    Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    ' Define Gmail configuration
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True               ' Enalbe SSL
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1            ' SMTP Authentication ON
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = Gmail_SMTP         ' SMTP Server address
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25               ' SMTP port
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2                   ' SMTP encryption
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = Gmail_ID         ' Gmail ID
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = Gmail_PWD        ' Gmail PWD
    NewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update                                                                                 ' Update all settings

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
                FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        .Close savechanges:=False
        On Error Resume Next

        Gmail_attachment = TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

        'Set All Email Properties
        With NewMail
          .From = Gmail_ID
          .To = SendTo
          .CC = SendCC
          .BCC = ""
          .Subject = Holidex & " System Login - " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " - " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy")
          .textbody = "The following client has just logged in to this system:" & vbNewLine _
                & "Date: " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ss") & vbNewLine _
                & "System: F&B Feedback Card Summary" & vbNewLine _
                & "Filename: " & ThisWorkbook.FullName

          '.HTMLBody = "Write your complete HTML Page"

        ' For multiple Attachment you can add below lines as many times
          .AddAttachment Gmail_attachment
        End With

        NewMail.Send  ' or use .display
        'MsgBox Gmail_attachment, vbOKOnly, "String"
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    ' Delete the duplicated worksheet and turn off prompts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .ActiveSheet.Select
            .ActiveSheet.Delete
            .Sheets("Summary").Select
        End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Clean up
        Set NewMail = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

The problem is here in this section where one adds the .attachment "C:\file.xls" variable

```
'Set All Email Properties
With NewMail
  .From = Gmail_ID
  .To = SendTo
  .CC = SendCC
  .BCC = ""
  .Subject = Holidex & " System Login - " & ThisWorkbook.Name & " - " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy")
  .textbody = "The following client has just logged in to this system:" & vbNewLine _
        & "Date: " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ss") & vbNewLine _
        & "System: F&B Feedback Card Summary" & vbNewLine _
        & "Filename: " & ThisWorkbook.FullName

  '.HTMLBody = "Write your complete HTML Page"

' For multiple Attachment you can add below lines as many times
  .AddAttachment Gmail_attachment
End With
```

Comment: What does return `MsgBox Gmail_attachment`?

Comment: it just returns me to path to have a look at the file. First I suspected an error in the file path, but the file is ok, has content, is not in a protected folder, etc. etc. Really no clue why it doesnt like the variable approach

Comment: Ha! Finally found the problem. Unlike with outlook's SendMail approach, this script will not attach any files that are actively open. I moved the `.Close savechanges:=False` to right after the .saveas dialog, which means that the temp file was closed at the moment of being attached, which finally solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The script does not support attaching open workbooks, hence I had to place `.Close savechanges:=False` right after the save dialog which solved the issue. Original post has been edited.